# Copy only the search expression results from a textfile in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a source code and want simply to copy the strings which I find with an regular expression.

Just like:

```
asdladhsfhjk-hello1-asdlkajhsd
asdsa-hello3-asdhjkl
asdölkj-hello5-
```

that I simply want to copy the -helloX- from the text. And not the line..

How do I do it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[**update**: see extended instructions below if you are working with a file that has
1. lines with and lines without the pattern and
2. you want to erase all lines without the pattern and
3. only preserve the pattern from the remaining lines
].

Do a regular expression Find and Replace, with the search pattern as `^.*?(-hello[0-9]+-).*$` and the replacement as `\1`.

[image: find and replace dialog in notepad++]

1. That finds a non-greedy match (match will be as small as it can) at the beginning of the line for anything, like so: `^.*?`.
2. Then your pattern is in `()`, so that it  can be captured in a capture group.
3. Then we match the rest of the line `.*$`.
4. The `\1` is the contents of the capture group matched in the `()`s.

---

**Here's how to delete non-pattern lines and preserve only the patterns from lines with the pattern.**

1. Bookmark all lines with the pattern:

[image]

2. Delete the un-bookmarked lines, so that now you only have lines with the pattern.

[image]

3. Now you can run the regex find and replace as above (first part of answer) to keep only the pattern from the remaining lines.

Comment: I am not a regex profi. My pattern is file=/uploads/tx_flvplayer/<video_name>.flv And I can't get your code work with this...

Comment: is `video_name` what you want to find and keep?

Comment: no. Whole /uploads/tx_flvplayer/<video_name>.flv is what I want to keep.

Comment: Ok, then your pattern would be something like this `^.*?(/uploads/tx_flvplayer/<[^>]+>\.flv).*$`

Comment: Thank you, But now only the lines get affected. but I want to delete all other lines with it! Not only replace it.. I really just want to copy a discontinous text..thats all..

Comment: So you want to delete lines when the lines do not have the pattern, and keep only the pattern for lines that have the pattern, is that right?

Comment: @caniko: see the additional material I added.  I'm thinking this is what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: @DWright If my regex spans multiple lines, is there a way to bookmark all of them?

Comment: DWright Yeah this only bookmarks the first line of the multi line match sadly.
@iraserd I managed to work around this in some cases by find->replacing the new line characters (eg [\r\n]+ for notepadd++) for the blocks I wanted to mark - so they are one line. Then markable with the above method.

Comment: Just awesome! Why doesn't someone give a bounty to this answer? @Caniko

Comment: This answer has just saved me considerable time extracting some (probably otherwise lost) data out of log files. @DWright if I'm ever in your neck of the woods, I owe you a beer!