# Extract the ID value, WITH "

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++, extract

Given the following code:

```
<div class="image-holder ui-draggable" title="something" id="image-138-1" 
style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;http://example.com/userdata/138/image_5beb36c29fe79f5590054d05164c88f7.
gif&quot;); left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative;"></div><div 
class="image-holder ui-draggable" title="something2" id="image-15230-4" 
style="height: 40px; width: 40px; background-image: url(&quot;http://example.com/userdata/135238/image_5beb36c29fwrdfsdfd05164c88f7.g
if&quot;); left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative;"></div><div 
class="image-holder ui-draggable" title="somethinggfhgf" id="image-1388973-1" 
style="height: 30px; width: 10px; background-image: url(&quot;http://example.com/userdata/13456548/image_5beb3646456164c88f7.gif&quot
;); left: 0px; top: 50px; position: relative;"></div>
```

How can I extract, using Notepad++, the id-s values, with " ".
Example: "image-138-1" "image-15230-4" "image-1388973-1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `(?<=id=)"image-\d+-\d+"` will look for the literal text `"image-` followed by one or more digits followed by the literal text `-` followed by one or more digits followed by the literal text `"`.  This all must be preceded by the literal text `id=`, however that will not be present in the resulting match..

Performing a `Find All in Current Document` using this pattern...

[image: Notepad++ Find dialog]

...matches the three example strings you listed (but not the preceding `id=`) on lines 1, 4 and, 7.

[image: Notepad++ main window with Find results]

### Edit:

Based on [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/477686/34985) (and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218381/150605) shows the same concept), I was able to get the following to work:

1. `Search` ⮕ `Replace...` in `Regular expression` mode with `Find what: (?<=id=)("image-\d+-\d+")` and `Replace with: \n%\1%\n`.  Click the `Replace All` button.
2. `Search` ⮕ `Mark...` in `Regular expression` mode with `Find what: %(.*?)%` and `Bookmark line` enabled.  Click the `Mark All` button.
3. `Search` ⮕ `Bookmark` ⮕ `Remove Unmarked Lines`
4. *(Optional)* `Search` ⮕ `Bookmark` ⮕ `Clear All Bookmarks`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It just gives me as result the first line. (multiple times) :(

Comment: When I copied the HTML from your question it pasted as 9 lines of text.  Is it really just one line of text?  If that's the case then, yes, each line will appear once per match, with each match highlighted.  You'll likely need to scroll horizontally to see them all.  Alternatively, use the `Find Next` button instead to cycle through the matches.

Comment: I tried just as you said, but it still doesn't work. It only shows me the first line...

Comment: I can't speak to what would cause that without knowing what your input (still not clear if you have 40,000 `<div>` elements in 40,000 lines or 40,000 `<div>` elements in just one line) and Find command look like.  How do they compare to my screenshots?  Also, am I correct in assuming that, ultimately, you want to end up with something like a document containing the value of all `id=""` attributes one per line which you can then manipulate further?  If so, I'm not sure how Notepad++ could be used to do that because, as we see, the Find results include the entire line, not just the matched text.

Comment: If I use the Mark option, it does mark everything I need, but I can't copy-paste them. =/

Comment: Are you on Windows, by chance?  (Edit: Duh.  You're using Notepad++.)  This doesn't answer the question as-asked, but if it were me I would just forget Notepad++ and use PowerShell instead with the same regex.  If you run `Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern '(?<=id=)"image-\d+-\d+"' -Path 'input.txt' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Matches' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Value' | Set-Content -Path 'output.txt'` it will find all matches (whether one- or multiple-per-line) in `input.txt` in the current directory and write them one-per-line to `output.txt`.

Comment: I finally managed to get the result of your first answer, but how do I copy the result?

Comment: I don't believe you can copy just the matches from the Find results.  Please see my edit to this answer, though, for a method I was able to get to work.